# Question about the range of $f(x,y)=\frac{x\cos x + y \sin y}{x^2+y^2+\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, compactness, connectedness

Let $~X = \{(x,y)∈ℝ^2∶|x| ≤1,~|y|≤1\}$ and function $f : X →ℝ$ defined by $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x\cos x + y \sin y}{x^2+y^2+\alpha}$$where $\alpha\gt0$, then the range of $f(x,y)$ is
$a)~~$ not compact set
$b)~~$ bounded open set
$c)~~$ connected open set
$d)~~$ connected closed set

How to find the range of $f(x,y)$ and the further things ?

Clearly, since $\alpha\gt0$, for any value of $(x,y),~~x^2+y^2+\alpha\ne0$ and therefore $f(x,y)$ is defined for all values of $(x,y)$. Now how to proceed further ?

Comment: You do not have to find it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't need to know the range of $f$ in order to answer those questions.

$f~$ is continuous as being the fraction of two continuous maps where the denominator is not vanishing. This enables to answer the questions.

**a)** $X$ is closed and bounded. Therefore compact. As the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact, the range of $f$, $~f[X]$, is compact. **Answer for option (a) is no.**

**b)** According to the above discussion, the range of $f~$ is bounded and closed. As it is not empty, it is not open. **Answer for option (b) is no.**

**c)** The image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected but it is not open according to previous discussion.  **Answer for option (c) is no also.**

**d)** **Summing up the previous options, answer for option (d) is positive**  i.e., only **option (d) is correct.**

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you @mathcounterexample.net

Comment: I made some modification on your answer as I felt that there were some linguistic inconsistency. If I am wrong, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous and the domain is compact and connected so the range is compact and connected also.  d) is the right one.